# How to use the each pair of values in column and transpose them into rows inside groups (groupby)

Tags: pandas, loops, group-by

I have data on which I already applied group by user and sort by time (`data.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('time'))`
):

```
user     time     point_id
 1       00:00         1
 1       00:01         3
 1       00:02         4
 1       00:03         2

 2       00:00         1
 2       00:05         3
 2       00:15         1

 3       00:00         1
 3       01:00         2
 3       02:00         3
```

And from that I need to inside each group to made links/transpose next 2 values into rows. It should look like this for the example above:

```
user     start_point     end_point
 1           1               3
 1           3               4
 1           4               2

 2           1               3
 2           3               1

 3           1               2    
 3           2               3
```

My final goal is to get matrix which will show how many links come into each point:

```
point_id |  1   |     2    |    3   |     4    |
    --------------------------------------------
   1         0        1         3          0
   2         1        0         0          1
   3         3        0         0          1
   4         0        1         1          0
```

So this matrix means that from point 2 one link goes to point 1, from point 3 that 3 links go to the point one and etc.
The picture of this looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can use `shift()` to group `point_id` into rows.

```
df = df.assign(end_point=df['point_id'].shift(-1))[df['user']==df['user'].shift(-1)].rename(columns={'point_id':'start_point'}).astype(int)
print(df)

   user  start_point  end_point
0     1            1          3
1     1            3          4
2     1            4          2
4     2            1          3
5     2            3          1
7     3            1          2
8     3            2          3
```

Then you can use `pd.crosstab` to count directed link.

```
u = pd.crosstab(df.start_point, df.end_point)
print(u)

end_point    1  2  3  4
start_point            
1            0  1  2  0
2            0  0  1  0
3            1  0  0  1
4            0  1  0  0
```

According to your results, what you need is undirected graph counting, so all we need to do is transpose and add.

```
result = u + u.T
print(result)

end_point    1  2  3  4
start_point            
1            0  1  3  0
2            1  0  1  1
3            3  1  0  1
4            0  1  1  0
```

**Final code** as follow:

```
df = df.assign(end_point=df['point_id'].shift(-1))[df['user']==df['user'].shift(-1)].rename(columns={'point_id':'start_point'}).astype(int)
u = pd.crosstab(df.start_point, df.end_point)
result = u + u.T
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) 
For some reason, I don't get the zeros on the diagonal. :O

Comment: @Neven What do you mean with `don't get the zeros on the diagonal`?

Comment: Nothing, I already solve the problem. Thank you. You really helped me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this works for your example, taking `df = data.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('time'))` (your starting example):

```
groups = [(k, df.loc[v, 'point_id'].values) for k, v in df.groupby('user').groups.items()]

res = []
for g in groups:
    res.append([(g[0], i) for i in (zip(g[1], g[1][1:]))])

df1 = pd.DataFrame([item for sublist in res for item in sublist])
df2 = df1.copy()

df2.iloc[:,-1] = df2.iloc[:,-1].apply(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))  # df2 swaps around the points

df_ = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values(by=0)  

df_['1'], df_['2'] = df_.iloc[:,-1].apply(lambda x: x[0]), df_.iloc[:,-1].apply(lambda x: x[1])

df_ = df_.drop(columns=1)
df_.columns = ['user', 'start_point', 'end_point']  # your intermediate table

df_.pivot_table(index='start_point', columns='end_point', aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
           user
end_point   1   2       3       4

start_point                 
1          0.0  1.0     3.0     0.0
2          1.0  0.0     1.0     1.0
3          3.0  1.0     0.0     1.0
4          0.0  1.0     1.0     0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) I am w8ing for an algorithm to finish, I have a really huge dataset.

Comment: And my algorithm still has not finished. I accepted the above answer because it is a more optimal solution for the large dataset that I have. 
But thank you very very much! I gave you thumb up. :)